# Is there is a way to know what configuration class creates bean?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, javabeans, component-scan

I wonder if there is a way in Spring to know what configuration triggers creation of a particular bean? So the case is the following: there are some `@Configuration` marked classes, some of them may be also annotated with `@ComponentScan` annotation. How can I figure out which of this configurations triggers creation of a particular bean? I mean triggers processing `@Component` annotation, only this case.
Thanks for any thoughts in advance!

Comment: The `@Configuration` classes don't create beans, unless you're talking about `@Bean` annotated methods. They just supply the `@ComponentScan` information to the Spring framework, which does the actual scanning and bean creation, including the creation of the `@Configuration` beans themselves.

Comment: @Andreas I understand it. Spring processes the `@Configuration` annotation, searches for `@Component` annotated classes if needed and creates beans. But it is a configuration class that triggers this search as far as I understand. Just to make it more clear: I'm working on a maven plugin.

Comment: Correct, but that is not how your question is phrased: *"How can I figure out which of this configurations creates a particular bean?"* The configuration doesn't *create* the beans. Edit and clarify your question if that is not what you intended to ask.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the note, I've edited the question.